# Validating akka-stream Source in unit test

Tags: scala, unit-testing, akka-stream

What is idiomatic way of validating a akka-stream Source in a unit test?
I am doing like this:

```
f.service.fetchData(id).flatMap {
          case Right(source) => {
            // TODO: I need to validate here that source contains "Test value"
          }
          case Left(_) => fail("Wrongly responded with error")
        }
```

source is basically:

```
Source.single(ByteString("Test value"))
```

I tried to execute by connecting Source to a Sink and checking the emitted values, but assertions don't seem to work.

Comment: Got it working with:
source
          .fold("") { case (x, y) =>
            x + y.decodeString("UTF-8")
          }
          .runWith(Sink.head)
          .await

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way of testing Sources, Flows and Sinks is by using [test probes](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-testkit.html#testing-streams).

Given following source the logic of witch you want to test

```scala
val source = Source(Seq("TestValue")).collect {
  case s @ "TestValue" => Right[String, String](s)
  case _               => Left[String, String]("error")
}
```

(I know that `Left` will never trigger here but it's just an example)

Now, you can define a `TestSink` that is connected to the given source. The resulting graph is executed in following way

```scala
"assert correct value" in {
  implicit val system: ActorSystem = ???
  val probe = source.toMat(TestSink.probe)(Keep.right).run()
  probe.request(1)
  probe.expectNext(Right("TestValue"))
}
```

`TestSink.probe` is a sink that materializes into a `TestSubscriber.Probe[T]` and it provides controls over the stream. Since it's a sink, it needs to emit demand for an element. It does it via `request(1)` or request one element. Then it's followed by assert `sink.expectNext(Right("TestValue"))` that checks that correct value is received.

There is also a counterpart called `TestSource.probe` that allows testing of a `Sink`.

And by combing both of them, you can test a `Flow`.